# Getting "java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I am trying to run my application but every time I try to login into my application then this error comes up showing "IO Exception: The network adapter couldn't establish a connection. I created a JDBC connection pool successfully and ping also gets succeeded. Everything is done but don't know the reason why the project is not running kindly help!
[image]

As You can see in the above picture the Xampp Server is running and the database is also connected to localhost, Glassfish server is also running and connected to localhost. but every time the following error comes up.
[image]

Comment: This is an Oracle database error, but you have tagged MySQL. Which are you using Oracle or MySQL? If you're using MySQL, then you're using the wrong driver and JDBC url to connect.

Comment: I am using MYSql. Which driver I have to use then?

Comment: You have to use the MySQL Connector/J driver, and use a JDBC url that starts with `jdbc:mysql:` (or if you configure GlassFish using a data source, it needs to be a MySQL DataSource, or a generic DataSource that accepts JDBC urls).